# How to fix text on image so that it can move with text?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to fix text on image so that if my image moves or flips, my text also move or flip with the text. How can i do that ? I just want my text to be behave with the image animation.

Ex: If my image flips, Text on it should also flip.
    If my image pops out , then text should also pop out
    If my image moves , then text also come with it.

Overall , i just want to fix text on image.

Thanks

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: @ManojKadolkar do not suggest fiddle. SO has a code snippet that works very good . he should use that . Coder share your relevant code otherwise we can't help you and your question will be closed

Answer (score 1):

```css
.flip {
            width: 300px;
            height: 500px;
            perspective: 1000px;
        }
        .flip_box {
            width: 300px;
            height: 500px;
            position: relative;
            transition: all 0.4s linear;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d
        }
        .front, .back {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 500px;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            border: 1px solid #666;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        }
        .front {
            color: red;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .back {
            color: blue;
            font-size: 18px;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
        .flip:hover .flip_box {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
```

```html
<div class="flip">
    <div class="flip_box">
        <div class="front">
            Hello
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            Bye
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How you fixed these text so that they are flipping accordingly?

Comment: mainly i need to fix my text on image as u did.

Comment: I wrote css with example sir